Linux Ubuntu 22 freezing at boot when starting X session
I have a rather old lenovo X201 with Ubuntu installed. Has always worked fine.
Since about June, the X system freezes when logging as a user (GDM displays, but after the logging, mouse and keyboard completely stop working).
I have
Linux X201-ub22 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
xserver-xorg/jammy,now 1:7.7+23ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xwayland/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.13 amd64 [installed,automatic]

as kernel and x server.
The problem does not occur when starting in recovery mode.
I tried to look at the X logs, but did not spot anything special. I will collect the log now and put it here.
Any suggestion is welcome to investigate. Cheers xg
